# Ruby include? is throwing undefined method `include?' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError) error

Tags: ruby

I have the following essentially:

```
res = "CRITICAL- Code Cache:57% Par Eden:19% Par Survivor:21% Cms Old Gen:26% Cms Perm Gen:34% | CodeCache=57% ParEden=19% ParSurvivor=21% CmsOldGen=26% CmsPermGen=34%"

if res.include? "OK"
    puts res
    exit 0
elsif res.include? "WARNING"
    puts res
    exit 1
elsif res.include? "CRITICAL"
    puts res
exit 2
end
```

And when I run I am getting:

```
: undefined method `include?' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
```

And the wrong exit code.  I use this same if/elsif on another of my scripts, and it works perfectly, but not here, only difference is it isn't in a class.

Comment: Your current code is not helping to reproduce the error.. how are you getting value of `res` in your actual code.. Need a check there

Comment: My res = is actually a system() command that is passing another variable to a bash script which is parsing the data for me, and returning the string that I have above

Comment: Essentially you are performing your code on a variable with the value `false` before the `if`. Print it out to verify.

Comment: Only possibility is that res is not what you think. Print it out to confirm.

Comment: Ok, when I just do  puts res  it gives me the string, and false on a new line.  How can I strip the variable to just be a string?

Comment: Yes.. that's the problem - **[system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system) returns `true` if the command gives *zero exit status*, `false` for *non zero exit status*. Returns `nil` if command execution *fails*.** Use [*backtick*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-60)

Comment: I just googled a bit more. Apparently I can run a bash command by just using res = `tick here`. And that did what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

[As per the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152623/cashman04)

> My res = is actually a system() command that is passing another variable to a bash script which is parsing the data for me, and returning the string that I have above

Yes.. that's the problem - **[system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system) returns `true` if the command gives *zero exit status*, `false` for *non zero exit status*. Returns `nil` if command execution *fails*.**  Thus `res` will always have either `true` or `nil` or `false`, never a string, what you want it to be. Thus you need to use [*backtick*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-60), instead `system`.